# Exporting a destructured object possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, destructure, esmodules

I'm writing an ESmodule and have the following code:

```
const object = {
    key1: 'test',
    key2: 'test2',
}

export {
   ...object
}
```

It seems you can't export a destructured object?

Is there a workaround that would look clean?

Comment: The answer is no, es6 modules are static as allowing this would also allow dynamic exports which is not great as became apparent with CJS modules

Comment: You can't directly export "computed" data structures from an ESM module.  ESM exports must be statically known (without running the code).  In this specific export, you could just do `export object` since there's nothing else in what you're trying to export other than what's in the object you already have.

Comment: `export object` doesn't work, but I'm able to do `export default object`